# unpoly links attribute to load the link's url on DOMContentLoaded event

Tags: unpoly

In unpoly's docs I've found attributes for links to load their content on click, on press down and even on mouse hover events.

But I'd like to load and show some link's content when page is loaded.

Is there unpoly link's attribute to load the link's url on DOMContentLoaded event or on Window.Load event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't following a link on `load` replace the page you just loaded?

Anyway, this would be a way to activate a link as soon as it enters the DOM:

```
up.compiler('a.auto-follow', function(link) {
  up.follow(link)
})
```

Use it like this:

```html
<a class="auto-follow" href="...">...</a>
```

Comment: I don't want to reload the whole page, I want the link to have up_href and up_target attributes and load the content of the page by url defined in up_href and replace the content of DOM element on the page defined in up_target. But to do it without clicking the link, right on the first page load. Does your answer do this?

Comment: Can I just put a <span up-follow up-href="/foo/bar" up-target=".some-div">Go</span> into page and it will load the content of .some-div by url=/foo/bar into the same .some-div element on the current page right on the current page load?

Comment: Not yet, but I sure will, Thanks!  I've read the unpoly docs about up.compiler and it's absolutely what I want. I just hoped to have such attribute out of the box.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice but it does not do what I need, I need this link to load some content into some wrapper inside current page. I tried to give the link attribute up-target=".my-wrap" and placed the link inside <div class="my-wrap" in hope that the link will replace itself with the content of the page, in the loaded page I tried to wrap the needed content with the div of the same class, it didn't help too. The current page content is swapped out. Is there a way to achive what I need?

Comment: Sorry, everything works fine, had live code reload problems. Thanks!